# difference of javascript call() and apply() via implementation

Tags: javascript, oop

I've been watching videos and experimenting regarding javascript OOP. But still having no good results when it comes to `call()` and `apply()` methods. I want to send a message to a player using a function from a mailman named `send()` but it is always telling me:

> Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Here is an example:

```js
function Player(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.inbox = [];
}
Player.prototype.viewInbox = function() {
  return this.inbox;
}
Player.prototype.msgRecieve = function() {
  this.inbox.push({
    to: arguments[0],
    msg: arguments[1]
  });
}

function Mailman(branch) {
  this.branchName = branch;
  this.send = function(to, message) {
    to.msgRecieve.call(arguments);

  }
}

var anthony = new Player('anthony');
var ph = new Mailman('PH');

console.log(anthony.viewInbox()); //[]
ph.send('anthony', 'hello anthony'); //send 
console.log(anthony.viewInbox()); // expecting [object{to:'anthony', msg:'hello anthony'}]
```

Comment: 'antony' is a string, it doesn't have any 'msgRecieve' property.

Comment: `anthony` on the other hand (as opposed to `'anthony'`) is a *Player* object and *will* have the `msgReceive` property.

Comment: FWIW: It's "receive", not "recieve" ("'i' before 'e' except after 'c' or when sounded as 'a' as in neighbour and weigh").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to `call` should be the value that `this` should have during the function call; in the above, you want it to be `to`. Then you list the arguments discretely, or you use `apply` instead and use an array (or an `arguments` object). In this case, you just want to pass in `message` because you're using `to`, so:

```
to.msgRecieve.call(to, message);
```

`call` uses the first argument you give it as `this` within the function it calls, and passes the function it calls any further arguments you give it. So for instance:

```
foo.call(something, 'a', 'b', 'c');
```

...will call `foo`, and during the call to `foo` `this` will be `something` and foo's arguments are `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'`.

There's also `apply`, which is exactly the same except you give it the arguments for the function as an array (or as an `arguments` object):

```
foo.apply(something, ['a', 'b', 'c']);
```

There are a couple of other problems, though. As [destroy points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26903944/javascript-call-am-i-using-it-wrong/26903975#comment42359211_26903944), you've also used `'anthony'`, a string, rather than `anthony`, your variable. Then in `send`, you want to get `name` from `to` (or better yet, do it in `msgRecieve`.

```js
function Player(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.inbox = [];
}
Player.prototype.viewInbox = function() {
  return this.inbox;
}
Player.prototype.msgRecieve = function(msg) {
  this.inbox.push({
    to: this.name,   // <=== Change
    msg: msg         // <=== Change
  });
}

function Mailman(branch) {
  this.branchName = branch;
  this.send = function(to, message) {
    to.msgRecieve.call(to, message);  // <=== Change
  }
}

var anthony = new Player('anthony');
var ph = new Mailman('PH');

snippet.log(JSON.stringify(anthony.viewInbox())); //[]
ph.send(anthony, 'hello anthony'); //send // <=== Change
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(anthony.viewInbox())); // expecting [object{to:'anthony', msg:'hello anthony'}]
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: @loki9: I've updated to explain `call` and `apply` a bit more.

Comment: Thank you very much! i'll use this as my reference. :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Why did ECMA implement two different methods `call` and `apply` just differing by the way we provide arguments list?

Comment: @sabithpocker: First off, thank you *again* for another good edit. I really should drink my coffee before answering questions. :-) I don't know why Netscape (probably Eich himself) did that, but it's really convenient, so it's probably the reason for it. When you need to call another function with all of the arguments you were given, `otherFunc.apply(this, arguments);` is really handy. When you need to send discrete arguments, `otherFunc.call(this, arg, arg2)` is handy. We could have got by with just `apply`, but in the early days, creating the array might have been costly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Convenience looks like a good reason, thank you for that explanation. I will drop a mail for sure, always a big fan of your's :)